# Add some drawing on a map and map it's streets

Tags: google-maps, mapbox, autocad, mbtiles

I would like to use a layer on top of a google map and map the streets on this layer.

Specifically - I have autocad design and would like to implement it somehow into a map, using tiles (maybe MBTiles) and provide info on the design.

I'm familiar with google maps but not on how I can add this layer and information. I don't want to create polygons and polylines in code - I want to use to vector design, place it on the map and add data like street names and such.

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you'll need to use AutoCAD Map 3D or AutoCAD Civil 3D to extract the layer as a shape file which you can then use with Google Maps.